# URL Redirect to IP on LAN

Tags: iptables, redirect, squid, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to forward a port based on subdomain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/96469/is-there-a-way-to-forward-a-port-based-on-subdomain)

wOk here is what I need to do:

Listen on various ports and route to LAN IP addresses based on url and port.

So I have a number of domain names assigned to the same IP address and I need to redirect based on url–

Server1.domain.com:5902 --> 192.168.0.100:5902
Server2.domain.com:5902 --> 192.168.0.101:5902
Server1.domain.com:23 --> 192.168.0.110:23
Server2.domain.com:23 --> 192.168.0.111:23

I have an IIS server that does this kind of thing fine for http stuff but other ports are bupkis.

Can this be done sith squid or iptables or ????

Comment: Err.. are you looking to do HTTP 30x responses for VNC and Telnet traffic?  That would be less than successful.

Comment: This has been asked many times already: http://serverfault.com/questions/121112/hostname-based-port-forwarding or http://serverfault.com/questions/255055/dynamic-port-forwarding-based-on-hostname-or-originating-ip just to name two of them

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. Only HTTP provides a reliable way to know the name of the host the client was trying to reach.